# Namespace issue while transforamtion using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on XML transformation and facing wired issue when adds namespace. Below is my XML and XSL. Problem is that my transformed XML attached namespace attribute (xmlns="") to elab which i don't want. Appreciate your help

Input XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Catalog>
    <Books>
        <book1>Wise Otherwise</book1>
        <book2>Great Expectations</book2>
    </Books>
    <library>
        <Name> Forsyth </Name>
        <city> Cumming </city>
    </library>  
</Catalog>
```

Expected Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Import xmlns="http://example.com" ImportType="BASE">
   <Books>
      <book1>Wise Otherwise</book1>
      <book2>Great Expectations</book2>
   </Books>
   <elab>
      <Name> Forsyth </Name>
      <city> Cumming </city>
   </elab>
</Import>
```

Below is my XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>   
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="library">
    <elab>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </elab>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Catalog">
    <Import xmlns="http://example.com" ImportType="BASE">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Import>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your template matching `library` creates the `elab` element in no namespace, so the serializer must add the `xmlns=""` to serialize the resulting tree accurately.  If you move the `xmlns="http://example.com"` up to the `xsl:stylesheet` element, then *all* unprefixed literal result elements in the stylesheet will be in this namespace, and you'll get the result you require:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://example.com" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>   
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="library">
    <elab>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </elab>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Catalog">
    <Import ImportType="BASE">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Import>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The more general point here is that when you're working with XSLT (or any namespace-aware XML tool) don't think about the `xmlns` "attributes"<sup>1</sup> but rather think about creating your elements in the right namespaces to start with and the namespace bindings will take care of themselves.

<sup>1: I call them "attributes" in quotes because they're not actually attributes as far as the XML data model is concerned and you can't manipulate them as if they were</sup>